# How to upgrade sonarqube through zip file

Tags: sonarqube, aem

I'm using sonarqube for AEM. But when I run **mvn sonar:sonar** on any module, it shows an error and the project analysis results in failure. Attaching the screenshot for that[image]

I tried upgrading sonarqube too. But I'm not able to do that. Steps mentioned in the sonarqube docs are not quite understandable. Please let me know if there is any solution for this.

Tried upgrading the sonarqube but not able to do that. If that could solve my problem, suggest me how to do that.

Comment: What versions? What does the elasticsearch logs (es.log) say? Also, post the error as text (code block/pre-formatted), not an image.